# Why LSP restrict that the text edit range of a completion item must be single line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol

In LSP spec about the completion item, there is a note says:

```
The text edit's range as well as both ranges from an insert
replace edit must be a [single line] and they must contain the position
at which completion has been requested.
```

Is there any reason that the range must be a single line?

> When the range is not a single line, the VS Code client will filter them out from the list.

For example:

```
a.|foo(() -> {
    ...
});
```

When triggering completion at `|`, I hope the completion item can change to code to:

```
a.bar(() -> {
    ...
});
```

In this case, the range of the text edit is multiline, but is not allowed in LSP.

Comment: why would you allow a prefix to a completion item to be more than 1 line, no language allows a variable name to be split on 2 lines

Comment: For example, when completing a lambda expression

Comment: the result is allowed to be multiple lines, not the range you want to replace, you don't match multiple lines to see if you have a completion item for the current cursor position

Comment: I add an example in the question description. I think VS Code team has their reason to dis-allow this. Maybe it will introduce some problems. I'm wondering why?

Comment: I don't see multi line replacement, you change `foo` to `bar`

Comment: The lambda body can be anything and they are not necessarily the same. I think we are off the topic. The question is why multi-line is not allowed. Like: if doing multi line replacement, something will be broken and what is that.